# Centering JPanel on JPanel and centering view on (JUNG) graph

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jung

I have an application, where I get vertices and edges of a graph as input and draw that graph. When the application launches, since there is no graph to show, I put on a place holder panel and later on add the jpanel that has the graph drawn on it to the place holder panel. But the problem is that I had to set the sizes manually. I am using JUNG to draw the graphs.

(Questions are unrelated? but I didn't want to create two different posts.)

First question: Is there a way to automatically add the graph panel so that it uses the whole area of the place holder panel? Below is a screenshot of how it currently looks.

Second question: When I add, because I set the JUNG graph layout very large, the graph is not centered. I have to search for graph. I want the graph to be centered on the view. how to do that?

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jieGp.png]

As it can be seen in the screenshot, the second panel kinda looks ugly and doesn't look like it is part of the panel. I want the place holder panel to have a fixed size, and then the graph panel to be as wide as that, no matter how big/small the graph is. If the graph is larger then it should activate the scroll bars, if not then no scroll bar should be shown.

Here is my place holder panel:

```
    placeHolderPanel = new JPanel();
    blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
    title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackLine,"Graph");
    title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT);
    border = title.getBorder();
    margin = new EmptyBorder(15,15,15,15);
    title.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(margin,border));

    placeHolderPanel.setBorder(title);
    placeHolderPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    placeHolderPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
```

After a button is clicked this is how I add the graph panel to place holder panel(table is a table that has all the data for drawing the graph):

```
    placeHolderPanel.add(new GraphPanel(table));
    placeHolderPanel.repaint();
    placeHolderPanel.revalidate();
```

Here is how graph is visualized, using JUNG:

```
    graph =  new MyGraphCreationClass(vertices,edges).getGraph();

    layout = new CircleLayout(graph);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    //BasicVisualizationServer<Integer,String> vv =
             //new BasicVisualizationServer<Integer,String>(layout);
    vv = new VisualizationViewer<Integer, String>(layout);
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,208));
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line<Integer,String>());
    vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);
    vv.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    vv.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    gm = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
    gm.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.TRANSFORMING);
    vv.setGraphMouse(gm);

    ScalingControl visualizationViewerScalingControl
    = new CrossoverScalingControl();

    vv.scaleToLayout(visualizationViewerScalingControl);

    scrollPane = new GraphZoomScrollPane(vv);

    //scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
```

Comment: `Questions are unrelated? but I didn't want to create two different posts` - Well if the question is unrelated then each question should have a different post. Its gets confusing when you have comments/answer related to different questions. Also, when you ask a question you should be "accepting" the best answer for your question. But you can only ever accept one answer per question. However, these questions are somewhat related since they are both related to screen layout.

Comment: The placeholder panel should probably use a BorderLayout. Then any component added to it will take up all the space available.